# Where can I find a good Civilization 4 Strategy guide?

Tags: civilization-4

I love this game but have a tough time winning past the 3rd level of difficulty...  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend [Civ Fanatics](http://www.civfanatics.com/). As a bonus, they've got information on Civ III and Civ V as well.

Here's a direct link to their strategy section: http://www.civfanatics.com/civ4/strategy

Comment: Civ Fanatics is also the home of the Fall From Heaven 2 mod which pretty much turns Civ 4 into a whole new (awesome) game.

Answer (score 2):

I use GameFaqs for all of my FAQ needs. Here is a link to the generic Civ4 listing, but they have FAQs specific to each edition, goty etc, as well.

http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/919352-civilization-iv/faqs

Answer (score 0):

- https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/sisiutils-strategy-guide-for-beginners.165632 - famous guide (not for PRO)
- http://www.sullla.com/civ4intro.html + http://www.sullla.com/civ4.html - commented games with screenshots
- https://www.youtube.com/user/Chris67132/playlists - guy plays/wins on Deity difficulty level, copy him.